# How to initialize log4j using a log4jproperties file outside classpath

Tags: java, log4j, war

How can we initialize log4j using a property file in custom location.

I have been trying to initialize log4j for my web application but it fails to read the log4j property file.

I am trying to take the location from one base config file and initialize using property configuration.

I read the config file and store the location to a variable.

```
         log4jpath =C://Users//log4j.properties

         PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jpath));
```

But this doesn't work at all. Log4j is only working when I put propert file inside the war file.

How can we place the property file in a custom location instead of binding it to the war.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:yourLocation/log4j.properties
```

Comment: Is there any other way ? I am trying to make the location to be read from a properties file